# How to Generate Text File from API Source?

Tags: c#, console-application, streamwriter

I have a small problem. I just recently started using Twilio's API to generate a record of messages that was sent to my assigned SID and Auth Token. However my question is how can I generate a text file, based off of what the console writes from the source its addressed to?

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Twilio;



namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account 
            string AccountSid = "X";
            string AuthToken = "X";
            var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

            // Build the parameters 
            var options = new MessageListRequest();
            options.From = "2015-07-01";
            options.To = "2015-07-13";

            var messages = twilio.ListMessages(options);
            foreach (var message in messages.Messages)
            {
                        Console.WriteLine(message.Body);
                        Console.Read();



                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing to a text file is pretty much boilerplate. The methods are shown here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx